# Why there are two sequential screen processes?

Tags: gnu-screen

I have one computer running Debian Wheezy(screen version *4.01.00devel*) and another one Debian Squeeze(screen version *4.00.03jw4*) and under both of them screen automatically starts another process named screen. For example:

```
init(1)-+-acpid(1926)
        |-sshd(2139)---sshd(2375)---bash(2448)---screen(6649)---screen(6650)-+-bash(6651)---pstree(6751)
```

According to `ps` PID 6649 command is `screen` and PID 6650 command is `SCREEN`:

```
root@vserver:~# ps -f -p 6650
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      6650  6649  0 11:26 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN
root@vserver:~#
```

Why does `screen` behave like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer `screen` (PID 6649) connects to the terminal you started from, and is terminated when you detach (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>).

The inner `screen` (PID 6650) is *not* connected to that terminal, but rather controls its own pseudo-terminal (pty) device, to which the `bash` started from it is connected.

What happens is that when you enter something on the outer terminal, the outer `screen` gets it, sends it over a socket to the inner screen, and that in turn forwards the input to the pty it controls, so it ultimately reaches `bash` (or any other program started from bash, and controlled through the same pty). Output from bash (or any program started from it) will be sent to the inner `screen`'s pty, which causes the inner `screen` sent it through the socket to the outer `screen`, which ultimately sends it to the terminal you started `screen` from (which in your case is again a pty created by `ssh`). Note that the socket is controlled by the *inner* `screen`, which allows detaching and re-attaching (see below).

If you detach the `screen` instance, what happens is that the inner `screen`, and with it the pty it controls, continues to exist. This is why the processes connecting to it, will survive, even if they try to do I/O. However the outer `screen` will terminate, thus breaking the connection with the outer terminal. You can now for example terminate the `ssh` session, and thus destroy the corresponding pty, and it will not affect the inner `screen` nor the programs started by it, since they communicate through their own pty device.

If you now log in again (creating another pty), and then call `screen -r`, the newly created `screen` instance will be connected to the terminal you started it from (which is completely separate from the one the first instance was started from, since you destroyed that), and then use the socket provided by the inner `screen` instance to re-connect with the inner `screen`, which will then send the current state of its own pty to the "outer" `screen` to display again; afterwards, the same I/O transmission line happens as with the previous outer `screen` instance.

If you now do a `pstree`, you'll find *two* lines with `screen`: One starting at `sshd` and ending at the new "outer" `screen` instance, and one starting with the "inner" `screen` instance which now no longer has a parent since that terminated when you detached the `screen`.

So in short:

- The "outer" screen (PID 6649) connects with the terminal you're interacting with (in your case, the pty set up by `ssh`) and only lives as long as you're attached to the `screen` instance.
- The "inner" screen (PID 6650) provides a separate pty for the programs you start under screen, and also provides the socket used to communicate the terminal state between the outer and the inner `screen` instance. It lives until you terminate `screen` (as opposed to detaching).
- The separation is necessary to allow the controlled programs to survive the death of the outer pty (by being connected to a different pty which along with its controlling process — the inner `screen` — survives detaching from the outer terminal), as well as to re-attach (by having the surviving inner `screen` provide a socket to which new instances of `screen` can connect).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for the second process (the one with PID 6650 in your sample) is to close tty connection (stdin, stdout and stderr), so you could logout. logg back in later an retake onwship of screen.

As you can see, PID 6650 is not connected to a tty (TTY column says '?').